# Parse error after deploy Laravel 5.1 on shared hosting

Tags: php, upload, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5.1

**To get rid of Public folder:**

1. I moved everything in a folder named 'root' except public folder.
2. Move all public folder content in Root.
3. Changed `require __DIR__.'/root/bootstrap/autoload.php';` & `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/root/bootstrap/app.php';` in index.php at root folder.

Everything is working perfectly in localhost. I uploaded my project in a shared hosting. And change database information in .env and change the url in `Config\App.php` `'url' => 'localhost',` to `'url' => 'http://zamzam-transport.com/',`.

Now when I go to myproject.com it shows a Parse error 
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/zamzamtransport/public_html/index.php on line 50`

index.php:

```
require __DIR__.'/root/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/root/bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Another problem is my .env file is accessible.

Update at: 12 August 2015
My server is updated to PHP5.6 the site starts  working but the .env file is still accessible.

Comment: check the permission of file

Comment: Can you tell me, how can i do that?

Comment: connect your server by FTP right click on the file , there is a option named as permission. you can check there

Comment: check php version on your shared hosting if PHP >= 5.5.9 laravel5.1 will support otherwise not .

Comment: It's 5.4.34 @sixFingersMan

Comment: That's the problem. Your shared hosting have php 5.4.34 but laravel only support php >= 5.5.9 . So , update your php in shared hosting and I think  then it will work

Comment: the hosting belongs to other company. Is there anything I can do to run the application from my side? @sixFingersMan

Comment: @sixFingersMan Thanks for your comment. You were right, it was having problem for PHP version. can you please post an answer and let me accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had also faced similar problem. After doing some research , I found that laravel didn't support the php version.

```
laravel 5.1 will support only PHP >= 5.5.9
```

So,before set upping your laravel project make sure that the server requirements for the laravel are satisfied.

For more information see [Laravel Site](http://laravel.com/docs/master)